# Competition registration program using classes

Tags: python, class, instance

I have an assignment to create a code that would define 2 classes, a player and a team each of these having some parameters. Player is supposed to have a name, a number of skis, a number of sledges and a player index(number of games played by the player before).

I managed to define these attributes of the class but I'm having a hard time implementing the team class. Team is supposed to hold the name of the team and the number of players-the players cannot be just their names it must link to the class instance(player). I don't understand how to use the information provided in the player instance to implement team. Here's my code so far:

```
class Player:
def __init__(self, name, skis, index):
  self.name = name
  self.sledges = []
  self.skis = []
  self.index = index
pass


class Team:
def __init__(self, name, players):
      self.name = name
      self.players = [Player]
pass

def get_players_count()

def get_transport_capacity()

def get_average_index()
```

*Update
Thank you for your help, I have one more function to add, a function that would return the number of passengers a team could accommodate. I've tried something like this but I don't think the syntax is correct. The user inputs the number of places in each sledge so I need to iterate over the values in the list to get the number of places.

```
def get_transport_capacity(self):
    skis = len(Player.skis)
    for i in Player.sledges:
        sledges += Player.sledges[i]
    capacity = skis + sledges
    return capacity
```

Comment: what `get_transport_capacity` should return?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Right now, it is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, index):
        self.name = name
        self.sledges = []
        self.skis = []
        self.index = index 


 class Team:
    def __init__(self, name, players):
        self.name = name
        self.players = players

    def get_players_count(self):
        return len(self.players)

    def add_player(self, player):
        self.players.append(player)

    def get_average_index(self):
        indexes = sum(list(map(lambda p: p.index, self.players)))
        count = self.get_players_count()
        return float(indexes) / count
```

Usage:

```
a = Player('AName', 2)
b = Player('BName', 11)
team = Team('TeamName', [a, b])
```

Comment: what does `indexes = sum(list(lambda p: p.index, self.players))` suppose to do ? maybe you wanted to type `sum(list(map(lambda p: p.index, self.players)))`

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
self.players = [Player]
```

why not:

```
self.players = []
```

And then have a method to add players to the team as in:

```
def add_player(self, player):
     # ensure optionally that player is a PLayer instance
     assert type(player) == Player
     self.players += player
```